# "Hernach" and "danach"

Tags: grammar

Can "hernach" be replaced by "danach"? My book states that it means ***afterwards.***

> Ich ging zu Jana und ***hernach*** zu Klaus.
>
> Ich frühstückte und ***danach*** putzte mir die Zähne.

My question is : Is ***hernach*** used often in Germany or is it used in formal writing or in informal writing ? Or is it both?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"hernach" is an expression which is only used in some parts of Germany. It's a quite uncommon expression. Instead you should use a more common expression like "danach", "hinterher" oder "anschließend" which all mean "afterwards".

Your 2nd sentence is missing a word. The correct sentence is:

"Ich frühstückte und danach putzte ich mir die Zähne."

Comment: Alternativ kann der zweite Satz auch umgestellt werden: "Ich frühstückte und putzte mir danach die Zähne."